# FLOPS for training a CNN

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, benchmarking, conv-neural-network

I want to find the actual TFLOPs of my GPU while doing DeepLearning.

Is there any way to find the floating point operations necessary for training a model like ResNet50?

I found some ways online to determine the flops for inference (one image), but I'm not really sure how that would transfer for training.

I'm thinking it will be flops of model * number of images * epochs, but this way I'm not taking into account the back propagation.

I found some benchmarks that outputs the number of images processed / second, would this be helpful?